# MYSQL select 2 random rows from each categories

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a mysql table with columns like this:

```
`qid`, `category`, `question`, `choice_1`, `choice_2`, `choice_3`, `answer`
```

In this table I have 2000 data and there are 7 different 'category'. I want to fetch 15 random rows from this table with equal number from each category. Since I have 7 categories, it's not possible to get equal number of rows from each category. In this case I can get 3 from one category. How can I achieve that with one query?
I was thinking of getting 2 rows from each categories. Then I will have 14 rows in total, and then I can get 1 random row from the table and merge records. Please show me an example query for this. Thanks. Here is my actual table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `difi_questions` (
  `qid` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `question` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `choice_1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `choice_2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `choice_3` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `answer` enum('1','2','3') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`qid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1959 ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just fetch 2 per category as you described, and one random at the end. It is not one query, but one result-set, which might be what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category= 1 ORDER BY rand() limit 0,2) as t1
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category= 2 ORDER BY rand() limit 0,2) as t2
UNION 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category= 3 ORDER BY rand() limit 0,2) as t3
UNION
...
```

(The nested Select allows you to sort by rand() per category)
Nothing special so far - 2 random questions per category.

The tricky part now is to add the 15th, element **WITHOUT** selecting any of those you already have.

To achieve this with "one" call, You can do the following:

- Take the subset of 14 questions you have selected like above.
- Union this with a uncategorized set of random sorted things from the database. (limit 0,15)
- Select all from this result, limit 0,15.
- IF the first 14 elements of the LAST subquery are already selected - they will be removed due to `UNION`, and a independent 15th element is guaranteed.
- If the final inner query selects 15 distinct questions as well, the outer limit 0,15 will only take the first of them into the result.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category= 1 ORDER BY rand() limit 0,2) as t1
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category= 2 ORDER BY rand() limit 0,2) as t2
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category= 3 ORDER BY rand() limit 0,2) as t3
    UNION
    ...
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,15) as t8
) AS tx LIMIT 0,15
```

This is somewhat ugly, but should exactly do what you need: 2 random questions from EACH category, and finally a random question that has NOT been selected already from ANY category. A total of 15 questions at any time.

(Sidenode: You could as well run a second query, using `NOT IN ()` to dissallow already selected questions after determining the 14 questions for the 7 categories.)

Edit: Unfortunately SQL Fiddle is not working at the moment. Here's some fiddle code:

```
CREATE TABLE questions (id int(10), category int(10), question varchar(20));

INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(1,1,"Q1");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(2,1,"Q2");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(3,1,"Q3");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(4,2,"Q4");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(5,2,"Q5");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(6,2,"Q6");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(7,3,"Q7");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(8,3,"Q8");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(9,3,"Q9");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(10,4,"Q10");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(11,4,"Q11");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(12,4,"Q12");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(13,5,"Q13");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(14,5,"Q14");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(15,5,"Q15");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(16,6,"Q16");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(17,6,"Q17");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(18,6,"Q18");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(19,7,"Q19");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(20,7,"Q20");
INSERT INTO questions (id, category, question)VALUES(21,7,"Q21");
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category= 1 ORDER BY rand() limit 0,2) as t1
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category= 2 ORDER BY rand() limit 0,2) as t2
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category= 3 ORDER BY rand() limit 0,2) as t3
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category= 4 ORDER BY rand() limit 0,2) as t4
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category= 5 ORDER BY rand() limit 0,2) as t5
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category= 6 ORDER BY rand() limit 0,2) as t6
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category= 7 ORDER BY rand() limit 0,2) as t7
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,15) as t8
) AS tx LIMIT 0,15
```

the example data contains 3 questions per type, leading to the result that the 15th question (last row) is ALWAYS the one remaining from a category.

Comment: You lost me, but +1 anyway.

Comment: @Imrul.H Please note, that the first answer contained a `group by id` - this  does not work, so remove it, if you used that version :)

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out before and removed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `difi_questions_temp` (
  `qid` smallint(6) NOT NULL ,
  `category` varchar(255)  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO difi_questions_temp
select qid, category from (
SELECT qid, category
FROM difi_questions 
order by rand()) as x
GROUP BY category;


INSERT INTO difi_questions_temp
select qid, category from (
SELECT qid, category
FROM difi_questions 
where qid not in (select qid from difi_questions_temp)
order by rand()) as x
GROUP BY category;

insert into difi_questions_temp 
select qid, category from difi_questions
where qid not in (select qid from difi_questions_temp)
order by rand()
limit 1 ;

/*select qid,  category from difi_questions_temp order by category; */
select * from difi_questions where qid in ( select qid from difi_questions_temp);
drop table difi_questions_temp;
```