# how to split sql request into two sections (challenge)

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

I have the code below. Essentially, it takes math questions from a database and lays them out for an user to answer. There are two sections: mathcalc and mathnocalc. Right now, the program outputs both of them randomly.

Sometimes there can be 15 mathcalc and only 5 mathnocalc. This is a problem to me. I need to be able to specify that the program should only output 10 mathcalc and only 10 mathnocalc.

Furthermore, I want to be able to split up the output so that the first page is **only** mathcalc (it can be more than 1 page. I just need to print out all the mathnocalc **first** and then print out all the mathcalc after. essentially two groups).

I was wondering how I would incorporate that with my existing code. This is definitely challenging but I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me.

**Updated Full** code:

```
<?php 

session_start();

$email = $_SESSION['email'];

if (empty($email)) {
    echo "Not logged in";
}

else {
        require '../functions/convert_functions.php';
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $database = "questionbank";
        $answerkey = array();
        $typelist = array();
        $topiclist = array();
        $skilllist = array();

        $counter = 0;

        // Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
        $queryNoCalc = "SELECT question, type, Topic, Skill, imagename, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, correctanswer FROM goodquestions WHERE type = 'mathnocalc' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10";
        $queryCalc = "SELECT question, type, Topic, Skill, imagename, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, correctanswer FROM goodquestions WHERE type = 'mathcalc' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10";
        
        $noCalcResult = $conn->query($queryNoCalc);
        $CalcResult = $conn->query($queryCalc);
        
        if (($noCalcResult->num_rows > 0) && ($noCalcResult->num_rows > 0)){
            // output data of each row
            echo '<form method="post">';
            echo ' <div class="flex-container>';
            echo '<h3>NON CALULATOR SECTION</h3>';
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($noCalcResult)){
                echo "<div class='flex-child'>";
                echo "<p style='font-size:0.50em;color:#0e3c68;font-weight:bold;'>" . $row['question'] . "</p>";
                $correctanswer = $row['correctanswer'];
                $temptype = $row['type'];
                $temptopic = $row['Topic'];
                $tempskill = $row['Skill'];
           

                array_push($answerkey, "$correctanswer");
                array_push($typelist, "$temptype");
                array_push($topiclist, "$temptopic");
                array_push($skilllist, "$tempskill");

                if (empty($row['imagename'])) {

                }

                else {

                    

                    echo '  
                                <tr>  
                                    <td>  
                                            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row['imagename'] .'" height="125" width="125" class="img-thumnail" />  
                                    </td>  
                                </tr>  
                            ';  
                    
                }
                
                if ($row['type'] == 'mathnocalc') {

                    $typemessage = "No Calculator";


                }

                else {

                    $typemessage = "Calculator Allowed";

                }
                echo  '

                
                <div>

                <input type="radio" id="answerA-' . $counter . '" name= "answer-' . $counter .'" value="answerA" required> 
                <label style="font-size:0.40em;" for="answerA-' . $counter . '"> ' . $row['answerA'] . ' </label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="answerB-' . $counter . '" name="answer-' . $counter .'" value="answerB"> 
                <label style="font-size:0.40em;" for="answerB-' . $counter . '"> ' . $row['answerB'] . ' </label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="answerC-' . $counter . '" name="answer-' . $counter .'" value="answerC"> 
                <label style="font-size:0.40em;" for="answerC-' . $counter . '"> ' . $row['answerC'] . ' </label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="answerD-' . $counter . '" name="answer-' . $counter .'" value="answerD">
                <label style="font-size:0.40em;" for="answerD-' . $counter . '"> ' . $row['answerD'] . ' </label><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $counter . '">
                <p style="font-size:0.45em;"> ' . $typemessage . '</p>

                </div>
            ';
            
            echo'</div>';
            $counter++;   

            } //while end

        echo '</div>';
        
        echo '<div class="flex-container">';

        echo '<h3>CALULATOR SECTION</h3>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($CalcResult)) {
            
            echo "<div class='flex-child'>";
            echo "<p style='font-size:0.50em;color:#0e3c68;font-weight:bold;'>" . $row['question'] . "</p>";
            $correctanswer = $row['correctanswer'];
            $temptype = $row['type'];
            $temptopic = $row['Topic'];
            $tempskill = $row['Skill'];

            array_push($answerkey, "$correctanswer");
            array_push($typelist, "$temptype");
            array_push($topiclist, "$temptopic");
            array_push($skilllist, "$tempskill");

            if (empty($row['imagename'])) {

            }

            else {
    

            echo '  
                    <tr>  
                        <td>  
                            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row['imagename'] .'" height="125" width="125" class="img-thumnail" />  
                        </td>  
                    </tr>  
            ';  
                        
            }
                    
            if ($row['type'] == 'mathnocalc') {

                $typemessage = "No Calculator";


            }

            else {

                $typemessage = "Calculator Allowed";

            }
                echo  '

                    
                <div>

                    <input type="radio" id="answerA-' . $counter . '" name= "answer-' . $counter .'" value="answerA" required> 
                    <label style="font-size:0.40em;" for="answerA-' . $counter . '"> ' . $row['answerA'] . ' </label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="answerB-' . $counter . '" name="answer-' . $counter .'" value="answerB"> 
                    <label style="font-size:0.40em;" for="answerB-' . $counter . '"> ' . $row['answerB'] . ' </label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="answerC-' . $counter . '" name="answer-' . $counter .'" value="answerC"> 
                    <label style="font-size:0.40em;" for="answerC-' . $counter . '"> ' . $row['answerC'] . ' </label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="answerD-' . $counter . '" name="answer-' . $counter .'" value="answerD">
                    <label style="font-size:0.40em;" for="answerD-' . $counter . '"> ' . $row['answerD'] . ' </label><br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $counter . '">
                    <p style="font-size:0.45em;"> ' . $typemessage . '</p>

                </div>
                ';
                
                echo'</div>';
                $counter++;   
                
            
            }

                echo '</div>';
                echo '<input type="submit" name="checkanswer" value="Submit">';
                echo'</form>';   

            } 
            
            else {
                echo "0 results";
            
            }
   
        if(isset($_POST["answer"])) {
            
            foreach($answerkey as $output){
                echo $output . "<br>";
            }      
        
        }   

    
}

        

     
        
?>

<style>

.flex-container {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container > div {
font-size: 30px;

width: calc(50% - 2em);
  margin: 1em;
}

.test {
flex: 1 0 41%; /* explanation below */
font-size: 20px; 
}

.img {
 height: 100px;
 flex: 1 0 41%;
 width: 100px;
 }
 </style>

<html>

    <head>
    <title>Ensemble Education</title>

    <a>
        <form method ="post" action="#form-anchor" id="form-anchor">  
        <input type="submit" name="answer" value="Click for Answer Key">
    </a>
    </form>

    </head>
    
</html>


<?php



    if(isset($_POST["checkanswer"])) {
        
        $counter--;

        $sql = "SELECT Version FROM mathanswers WHERE email = '$email'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                $version = $row['Version'];

            }

            $version++;

        }

        else
        {

            $version = 1;


        }

        while ($counter != 0) {


            $answer = $_POST["answer-$counter"];
            
            $newcorrect = $answerkey[$counter];

           
             

            if (is_correct($answer, $newcorrect)) {

                $type = $typelist[$counter];
                $topic = $topiclist[$counter];
                $skill = $skilllist[$counter];
                $newtype = fix_type($type);

                $sql = "INSERT INTO mathanswers (Email, type, Topic, Skill, Correct, Version) VALUES ('$email', '$newtype', '$topic', '$skill', '1', '$version')"; 
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                
            }

            else {

                $type = $typelist[$counter];
                $topic = $topiclist[$counter];
                $skill = $skilllist[$counter];
                $newtype = fix_type($type);

                $sql = "INSERT INTO mathanswers (Email, type, Topic, Skill, Correct, Version) VALUES ('$email', '$newtype', '$topic', '$skill', '0', '$version')"; 
                $result = $conn->query($sql);


            }
            
            $counter--;
        }
        
        
        $URL="../studentprofile.php";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$URL}';</script>";
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">';
       
        
    }  




?>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the updated formatting error that results.
[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Vty.png)

Here is what I want it to look like.
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN2Dt.png)

Comment: What is the problem with the current output? And how your expected output look like?

Comment: @tcadidot0 the current output spews out both mathcalc and mathnocalc without any structure. I would like my output to print out ALL the mathcalc questions first and THEN the mathnocalc questions

Comment: This should be what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857920/mysql-select-2-random-rows-from-each-categories, you should use `UNION `

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495446/how-to-get-random-records-from-each-category-in-mysql, Look into this too..

Comment: @HarishST do you mind editing my code? I tried to implement it and I couldn’t seem to do it. It would truly mean a lot to me!

Comment: Hi Rushi, I have answered the question. Can you please check?

Comment: As an aside, seriously consider whether your design is optimal. 'Normal'ly, we'd have a separate table for answers, with a row for each answer, a column indicating if a given answer is correct, and a column indicating to which of 'A', 'B', 'C', or 'D' the answer belongs.

Comment: @HarishST I just implemented your code and it worked great. Is there anyway I can insert a partition between the nocalc questions and the calc questions? Basically I can have a header on top of the nocalc questions that say NO CALCULATOR ALLOWED. On top of the calc questions, I can say CALCULATOR ALLOWED

Comment: @HarishST I updated my code with your fix. However, the result was very poor. It led to disorganized sections. Try implementing the above code in your editor. I think there should be a few minor fixes. Let me know when you update the code

Comment: Yeah I spent the whole day debugging @HarishST. Can't seem to get a fix

Comment: Can you update with Current Result Screenshot? One Suggestion: When trying to write HTML and PHP in a PHP File. Try to write PHP inside HTML, not HTML inside PHP. Use PHP's alternative syntaxes for conditionals, loops etc to make it more readable. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: @HarishST I updated the code with the screenshot of it right now and my desired output. I would like it to be neatly organized as seen in the desired picture with the noncalculators first and then the calculators. Do you mind editing my code to implement this fix

Comment: @HarishST I just need this one last fix. please help

Comment: @RushiM There is no `Calculator` questions in the desired output. And about neatly organizing the contents is the job of HTML, CSS. Have you tried to look into the code that rendered in the browser? Checkout the Div positions and all.

Comment: @HarishST yes there are supposed to be calc questions in desired output i couldnt fit in the screenshot

Comment: @HarishST yes i have tried manipulating the rendered browser content. Do you mind trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, we are using 2 `SELECT` statements and use `UNION` to combine them into one result set.

```sql
SELECT question, type, Topic, Skill, imagename, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, correctanswer FROM goodquestions WHERE type = 'mathnocalc' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10
```

The above Query will return 10 random rows of type mathnocalc. That you will be sure about. I am using the above query as nested one to UNION with another one.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT question, type, Topic, Skill, imagename, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, correctanswer FROM goodquestions WHERE type = 'mathnocalc' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10) as cat1
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT question, type, Topic, Skill, imagename, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, correctanswer FROM goodquestions WHERE type = 'mathcalc' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10) as cat2
```

Try the above query and let me know the result.

For displaying the results based on categories, you can simply split the query into two:

Example Logic:

```php
$queryNoCalc = 'SELECT question, type, Topic, Skill, imagename, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, correctanswer FROM goodquestions WHERE type = 'mathnocalc' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10';
$noCalcResult variable will store the result set of above query.

Similarly,
$queryCalc = 'SELECT question, type, Topic, Skill, imagename, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, correctanswer FROM goodquestions WHERE type = 'mathcalc' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10';
$calcResult variable will store the result set of above query.
```

Now, you can use the seperate results in different DIV.

```html
<div class="no-calc">
  <h3>NO CALULATOR ALLOWED</h3>
  while ($noCalcResult):
    Do the stuff;
  endwhile;
</div>

<div class="calc">
  <h3>CALULATOR ALLOWED</h3>
  while ($queryCalc):
    Do the stuff;
  endwhile;
</div>
```

Hope you understand the concept.

Comment: check out my comment

Comment: If you are having trouble following nested queries then why not try seperate query for each type and dispaly it inside corresponding Divs?

Like Create Two Divs with Headings on it, then store the query results in seperate variables and loop through the result seperately. 

I know this is not optimized solution, but it would make it simple and easier to understand, so that you can build on top of it. Please let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: not quite sure how I would do this. Do you mind editing?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: check my comment above